# Create wordcloud from a data frame in R

Tags: r, frequency

I made a sample data frame. I try to make a wordcloud from the Projects column.

```
Hours<-c(2,3,4,2,1,1,3)
Project<-c("a","b","b","a","c","c","c")
Period<-c("2014-11-22","2014-11-23","2014-11-24","2014-11-22", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-24")
cd=data.frame(Project,Hours,Period)
```

Here is my code:

```
cd$Project<-as.character(cd$Project)
wordcloud(cd$Project,min.freq=1)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are missing the `freq` argument. You want to create a column indicating how often each project happened. I, therefore, transformed your data using `count` in the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud)

cd <- data.frame(Hours = c(2,3,4,2,1,1,3),
                 Project = c("a","b","b","a","c","c","c"),             
                 Period = c("2014-11-22","2014-11-23","2014-11-24",
                            "2014-11-22", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-23",
                            "2014-11-24"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cd2 <- count(cd, Project)

#  Project n
#1       a 2
#2       b 2
#3       c 3

wordcloud(words = cd2$Project, freq = cd2$n, min.freq = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you specify a character column, then the function creates a corpus and a document term matrix for you behind the scenes. The problem is that the default behavior for the TermDocumentMatrix function from the `tm` pacakge is that is only tracks words that are longer than three characters (also, it removes "stop words" so values like "a" would be removed). So if you changed your sample to

```
Project<-c("aaa","bbb","bbb","aaa","ccc","ccc","ccc")
```

it would work just fine. It appears there are no ways to change the control options sent to  TermDocumentMatrix. If you want to calculate the frequencies yourself in the same way that the default wordcloud function does, you can do

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(cd$Project))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
# corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords()))
tdm <-TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
freq <- slam::row_sums(tdm)
words <- names(freq)    

wordcloud(words, freq, min.freq=1)
```

however, for simple cases,  you could just count the frequencies with `table()`

```
tbl <- table(cd$Project)
wordcloud(names(tbl), tbl, min.freq=1)
```