# word cloud generation in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am sorry off this has been asked before. But I couldn't get my head around to get it working.

So I have a table like this:

where Col 1 is name and col 2 is the strength of that name.

```
ATF6    100.159 
SMAD4   101.765 
BACH2   101,852 
MAFF    105.397 
RFX3    105.869 
ESRRG   105.967 
RARB    114.81 
XBP1    120.215 
FOS 120.598 
BACH1   122.158 
NFE2    126.127
```

People have showed the example of two columns with numerical value. But how can I generate it from this format?  I think is quite straight forward but I am not just getting it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751378/create-wordcloud-from-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: And exactly which function/package are you trying to use to draw your word cloud.